# Issue with Gmail Annotations and Promotion Cards/Carousels

Tags: json, annotations, microdata, carousel-slider, gmail-promo-tab

Has anyone successfully made Product Carousels appear in the Promotion Tab? I've tried coding in JSON and MicroData, but we only get Deal Annotations with the logo, offer, promo code, and expiration dates. Even with 2, 4, or 10 images, the Carousel won't show up.
My code Previews fine in Google Workspace as per attachment.

Or is Product Carousel for Paid Advertisers only?

Any insights?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV9kX.png)

I've diligently followed all the requirements and guidelines provided by Google for implementing these features in our emails.

However, despite our best efforts, we haven't been able to get the Product Carousels to show up in the Promotion Tab. While some members of our team have successfully received Deal Annotations with the Organization logo, offer, promo code, and expiration dates, none of us have received the Carousel.

We've experimented with different scenarios, including coding in JSON and separately using MicroData. We've also tried using various numbers of images, ranging from 2 to a maximum of 10, but the Carousel still doesn't appear as expected.

The only instances I have seen of some other organization's Product Carousels showing up in my "Top Picks" promotion Tab were labeled as Ads. Is the Product carousel functionality only available for paid advertisements? We would appreciate clarification on this point.

We're eager to make this feature work as it can significantly enhance the user experience for our recipients. Any guidance or insights you can provide to help us resolve this issue and successfully implement Product Carousels in Gmail Annotations, whether for paid or non-paid content, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your email does not have to be a paid advertisement in order to use carousels. I will say, that it is a very finicky feature. Sometimes I see my product carousel and sometimes I do not. Most of the time, I do not even see the default code provided by Gmail for product carousels. If anyone else can weight in, please do!

Also, please add "gmail-promo-tab" as a tag in order for other engineers to see your post.

Comment: Thank you @Nader.
Done. Tag inserted.

Do any other engineers/developers here can help with carousels in the Promotion Tab?